# How can I start to build voice chat application c#

Tags: c#, audio, chat

what is the first step to get voice chat application?
I think first step get voice from input and convert it to byte and sent it in UDP connection to receiver then the receiver convert the byte to voice and play it and vice versa, so on until the disconnection

Comment: Have you taken a look at this article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19485/A-Voice-Chat-Application-in-C

Comment: I see that you also asked a question about NAudio. NAudio actually wrote a voice chat application. Its on their demo site. http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/920e758340dc.

Comment: On the left, select NAudioDemo, then NetworkChatDemo to explore the code. Also, you can download it and play with it to see more about how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a rather difficult task to explain in a single answer, so I will refer to some articles. You have the basic premise down, though.

Have you taken a look at this article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19485/A-Voice-Chat-Application-in-C
This one has some problems, but it could give a good solution if you want to do it in pure DirectShow.

I see that you also asked a question about NAudio. NAudio actually wrote a voice chat application. Its on their demo site. http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/920e758340dc

On the left, select NAudioDemo, then NetworkChatDemo to explore the code. Also, you can download it and play with it to see more about how it works.